# AngularJS document.ready doesn't work when using ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with document.ready in angularJS when navigating between several routes in my app. It only works when I use ctrl+f5 (page reload); it seems navigating between pages does not change state of the document to ready.

Controller

```
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,90);
});
```

Main html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app file

```
var mainModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap.dialog']);
function viewServiceConfig($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        controller: SomeController,
        templateUrl: 'somehtml.html'
    }).



    when('/someroute', {
        controller: SomeRouteController,
        templateUrl: 'someroutehtml.html'
    }).


    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}

mainModule.config(viewServiceConfig);
```

Comment: Did you tried jqLite' native `bind` method? Like `angular.element(document).bind("ready" , function(){...` ?

Comment: It's not clear how you're navigating between "pages" (are these `ng-view`s, `ng-include`s full document requests, ...?) but generally, you don't need to bind to `DOMContentLoaded` with Angular. Instead, you'd create a [Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: tnx @AndréDion . i use ng-view and use route in module configuration  like this

  when('/', {
            controller: SomeController,
            templateUrl: 'somehtml.html'
        }).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can listen in your controllers defined in routes i.e. `SomeController` and `SomeRouteController` for [`$viewContentLoaded` event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView). `$viewContentLoaded` is emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded and should provide similar functionality as the `document.ready` when routing in angularjs:

```
function SomeController($scope) {
   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {window.scrollTo(0,90);});
}
```

The `document.ready` is also triggered only once when you load your `index.html`. It is not triggered when the partial templates defined in your route configuration are loaded.

Comment: tnx . i use your solution and debug it with firebug . it scrolls page to that point but after page loads completely something reset scroll to  top of page

Comment: @SoheilGh Maybe try to change the listener to this `function(event) {event.preventDefault(); window.scrollTo(0,90);}`

Comment: tnx you . i use firebug to find out after which event page scrolls to top and i find it . i changed the event to $routeChangeSuccess and it works finally

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @davekr's answer, I found I need to add a $timeout to ensure the digest had complete and the html elements were available to query:

```
function SomeController($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $timeout(function(){
            //Do your stuff
        });
    });
}
```

I tried many other events and this was the only way that worked reliably.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to apply the scroll event through Dave's answer and by using [routeChangeSuccess](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route)

```
function SomeController($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {window.scrollTo(0,90);});
}
```