# gapi.client.item.get() function only works the first time application is loaded

Tags: angularjs, routes, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a  single page application which calls the initapi() function to bootstrap the document. I call the gapi.client.item.get() function inside a controller corresponding to one of the partials. The problem is it only works the first time i open the partial. 
When I try to reload the partial, it responds with the below error.

Failed to load resource: '(API URL here) http://dev-test-.....'
the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'gapi.client.item.get').

I do not understand the reason for this ? Can some one explain ?

Currently I am using manual bootstrap. Where in the onload callback function does the bootstraping of the application. Since its not working fine , I also tried implementing the other method which is calling the function on a global variable window and then defining it in a controller using the $window , which gives new error window.function undefined .

Answer (score 0):

The solution for window.function undefined has been solved using the $viewContentLoaded callback, that is fired every time ng-view loads. The problem is (document).ready in angularjs doesn't include the ng-views. 
check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945333/angularjs-document-ready-doesnt-work-when-using-ng-view)
This worked and now the cloud api is initialised  without manual bootstrapping.