# AngularJS Select Box Set Default Selected Value on Document Ready

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a weird problem when setting the model value of a dropdown on Document ready event. I want Option4 to be selected on page load, However this doesn't seems to be reflected on my view when I do things as follows. Please see below code...

HTML

```
<select ng-model="search_for" class="form-control" id="search_for">
                    <option value="">-Search For-</option>
                    <option value="1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option3</option>
                    <option value="4">Option4</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
$scope.search_for = 1;
}
```

Even when I do {{search_for}} in html it proves that model value is not set by showing nothing, but shows the value when dropdown value is changed.

What am I doing wrong ?.

Thank You.

Comment: instead of adding it on `document.ready` add at the starting in the controller, since the controller loads prior to view, the model value gets reflected

Comment: any reason why you can't use the "selected" tag provided in normal HTML to set what you want? Since it looks like it's hard-coded to set to a specific option anyway. Or do you just do everything in a new technology you are learning, ignoring all the other, already-built-in and easy to use standards?

Comment: Have you try with ng-init in select box ? otherwise please look here http://plnkr.co/edit/wTRXZYEPrZJRizEltQ2g?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding it on `document.ready` add at the starting in the `controller`, since the **controller loads prior to view, the model value gets reflected**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="search_for" class="form-control" id="search_for">
                    <option value="">-Search For-</option>
                    <option value="1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option3</option>
                    <option value="4">Option4</option>
</select> 

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.search_for = "2";
    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0jNP7egEHbDNz5NXoDHb?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much... !!! it works, but I don't understand why js can't manipulate and reflect the change on document ready. Can you please elaborate more... Cheers !!!

Comment: The document.ready is also triggered only once when you load your index.html. It is not triggered when the partial templates defined in your route configuration are loaded.

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945333/angularjs-document-ready-doesnt-work-when-using-ng-view)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ng-app and ng-controller for the app, without using **`document.ready`**

```js
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', [])
app.controller('akuaController', function($scope) {
 $scope.search_for = "1";
  
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="DemoApp"    ng-controller="akuaController">
  
  
  <select ng-model="search_for" class="form-control" id="search_for">
    <option value="">-Search For-</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
    <option value="4">Option4</option>
  </select>
  

 </body>

</html>
```